# Null expression with dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method with the following signatures that return a C# expression

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(IList<Filter> filters)
```

Then the following code that uses Dynamic LINQ

```
using (TestContext tEntities = new TestContext())
{
    var filterExp = Exp.ExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<Client>(filters);
    var filteredCollection = tEntities.Client.Where(filterExp);

    IQueryable<Client> queryResult;
    if (filterExp == null)
        queryResult = tEntities.Client;
    else
        queryResult = tEntities.Client.Where(filterExp);
}
```

This is a simple scenario.
I have queries that are 50 lines long sometimes more. I want to avoid having the same code twice with only difference using the where clause.

Does anyone knows if I achieve something different?

```
from product in context.Product.Where(deleg)
    .Include(x => x.Type)
    .Include(x => x.Category)
    .Include(x => x.WareHouse)
    .Include(x => x.Photos)
join f in context.Favorite on product.Id equals f.ProductFid into fg
from fgi in fg.Where(f => f.UserFid == userId).DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby product.Id descending
select new ProductngDto()
{
    ProductItem = product,
    FavoriteId = fgi != null ? fgi.Id : (long?)null
}).Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not really clear what you're asking, but i think you want: `IQueryable<Client> queryResult = tEntities.Client;`
`if (filterExp != null) {`
`queryResult = queryResult.Where(filterExp);`
`}`

Comment: @zaitsman I think he don't want his code to be repeated with just a slight difference in the where clause. Your comment will surely help him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the nice things about `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` is the fact that they are so abstract, you can easily chain them together. One solution could be to structure your code like this:

```
using (TestContext tEntities = new TestContext())
{
    var filterExp = Exp.ExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<Client>(filters);
    var filteredCollection = tEntities.Client.Where(filterExp);

    IQueryable<Client> queryResult = tEntities.Client;
    if (filterExp != null)
    {
        queryResult = queryResult.Where(filterExp);
    }
    //do something else with queryResult
}
```

This way you can continue using `queryResult` without having to know, or even care, about whether or not `filterExp` was applied.

For the second example, shuffling it around could look something like this:

```
var query = from p in context.Product
                      .Include(x => x.Type)
                      .Include(x => x.Category)
                      .Include(x => x.WareHouse)
                      .Include(x => x.Photos);

if (deleg != null)
{
    query = query.Where(deleg);
}

query = from product in query
        join f in context.Favorite on product.Id equals f.ProductFid into fg
        from fgi in fg.Where(f => f.UserFid == userId).DefaultIfEmpty();
        orderby product.Id descending
        select new ProductngDto()
        {
            ProductItem = product,
            FavoriteId = fgi != null ? fgi.Id : (long?)null
        }).Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Another option you have, is to check the `filterExp` for null and assign an "always true" lambda to it.
If you control the `GetExpression<T>` method, you could add it in there as a last step. If you don't control it, you could do the null checking in the methods where you use it's result.

This will allow you to keep your code looking a bit cleaner, but the trade-off is a small performance hit for having to evaluate the lambda all the time.

Depending on how your expressions are typed, this might be as easy as:

```
if (filterExp == null)
{
    filterExp = (_) => true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. It is an acceptable solution but how would you apply what you suggested in the second query that I added above and is my simpliest one?

Comment: Excellent thanks. I was looking for the always true condition (1=1).